# Cannot install Asphalt 8 from the Store

Tags: apps, settings, store, games, nokia-lumia-525

When I type "Asphalt 8" in the Windows Phone Store, only "Asphalt Hack" is returned,  not the game. When I clicked on a link for Asphalt 8 from the website, it took me to the store, but displayed an error.

How can I get this app?

Comment: What error message was displayed?

Comment: What is the region you are using in the phone?

Comment: Have you tried this link? http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/asphalt-8-airborne/3a9e6a13-433b-495d-879e-d4704fb40703

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your phone region in your setting to US region, then try to install again. By the way, please also provide the print screen to let us know how's the error you face. Thank you.